# Can I repair NM-B sheath stripped outside junction box?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, junction-box

This [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/111204/do-you-strip-the-outer-sheath-on-romex-when-it-enters-a-load-center-breaker-bo) confirms that the Romex™ (or NM-B) is supposed to come 1/4" into the box.  The prior owner had a box installed and the NM-B sheath was stripped back and does not reach the junction box. Can I wrap the now unsheathed but insulated wires with electric tape from where the sheath ends to the box as part of a repair?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the power to the circuit turned off, remove the cable from the junction box and examine it carefully to make sure the existing insulation hasn't been damaged by the cable clamp. If the insulation's OK, get some cable jacket repair tape from your electrical supply store and half lap it over the NM cable starting an inch or two over the existing sheath and continue to 1/4" into the box. Then half lap black vinyl electrical tape over the repair tape. This will provide more protection for the cable going into the cable clamp in the junction box than plain electrical tape.